# Django - load JSON file in template using CDN and access it's values

Tags: python, json, django, caching

I am developing a django app, I need to load some values off a json file that is served on with CDN. I would like to load it on the template so I can use Template fragments caching.
Given the url `cdn.domain.theroutetothisfile/file.json`. The file is updated every 48 hours.

I need to access some values on this json file, `description` something similar to:

```
<P>{{file.description}}</p>
  #where file is the loaded json
```

Searched for hours with no luck.

Also, should I cache the resources using `Memcached` on my RAM or caching to S3 using the `django-s3-cache` package ? which one is more efficient ?

Comment: This task cannot be done with Javascript using ajax request ?

Comment: @Abstonemonsieurbref the main problem is actually caching, I will go check out if the template cache work on Ajax requests, because using Ajax the request is ran after rendering the page, and therefore it might just keep requesting

Comment: There an option with jQuery ajax method to cache with GET request check this  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Template caching are done with the "with" keywords.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with.